# Should "if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)" be fine with 2 arguments? & terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' error

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, outofrangeexception

**Solution:** Use **`if (argc !=3)`** and **`getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ';')`**

This is a continuation of my previous question: [error: no matching function for call to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178519/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdvectorstdvectorintpush-bac), which allowed the code to compile without any errors

I am new to C++ and I am trying to debug this code from my supervisor.

The original code took a `csv` file as input, containing rows and columns of `integers`
   and `strings`. Now we're reading in a `txt` file having the shape:

`TEXT
       0; INT; INT; INT; INT; ...
       0; INT; INT; INT; INT; ...
       18 more lines of the above numbers and semicolons`

In that file I replaced in one instance the semicolons by line breaks and in another by empty spaces, because I was not sure which we needed. 
**Solution:** Use the **`txt`** file with the semicolons, but with the semicolons at the end of the lines removed.

- It seems to have an issue with **`if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)`** . It throws the "*Usage: ./a.o <> <>*" error message. However, both are strict inequalities. Shouldn't this **`if`** be fine with 2 arguments? In the original code it read **`if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)`** , which I changed it back to. 
  **EDIT:** As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) pointed out the "program name is an argument" as well, so I want actually 3 not 2.
- Both **`txt`** files (line breaks & spaces) seem to produce the same error message below

**Error message:** (For the **`int`** threshold I tried various values)

```
Registering only edges shorter than int.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Ideas:**

I am aware what this error message means when we have a simple case, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29062123/11791401):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(123); // v has 1 element  [0 to 0]
    int x4 = v.at(3); // exception
}
```

We get an exception, because v has 1 element and element 3 does not exist.

However, in my code I am not sure what exactly to look for.

The original code read a **`csv`** with lines and columns, but in this case a matrix form with empty spaces in between is probably causing issues. Does that mean that I just want a **`txt`** file looking like a column vector? That is one file I tried, so it might be that the code is not happy with the amount of columns?

**Relevant function:**

```
int main(int argc, char** threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename)
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./distanceMatrixToSageGraph.o <threshold> 

            <distanceMatrix_file_calculated_fromDGEsingleCell_data>" << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    string distanceMatrixfilename = threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[2];
    int threshold = std::stoi(threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[1]);
    std::ifstream distanceMatrixFile(distanceMatrixfilename);

    if (!distanceMatrixFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening distanceMatrix file: " << distanceMatrixfilename << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string row;
    std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row); // discard the first row, which specifies the format of the file.
    vector<vector<int>> the_entries;

    while (std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row))
    {
        std::stringstream row_as_stringstream(row);
        int i; i = 0;
        vector<string> row_as_vector;

        while (row_as_stringstream.good())
        {
            string substr;
            getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ',');
            row_as_vector.push_back( std::stoi(substr) );
        };
        the_entries.push_back(row_as_vector); //LINE 104
    };
}
```

**Whole code:**

```
// Convert distanceMatrix tables of protein interactions to SAGE graph.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void writeGraphInSageFormat(string name, std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges) 
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Write out the edges in SAGE format.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int edgeNumber = TheEdges.size();
    ofstream d1sageFile(name, ios::out);
    d1sageFile << "g = Graph([" << endl;

    for (int n = 0; n < edgeNumber; n++) {
        d1sageFile << "(" << TheEdges[n][0] + 1 << "," << TheEdges[n][1] + 1 << ")," << endl;
    }
    d1sageFile << "])" << endl;
    d1sageFile << "g.show()" << endl;
    d1sageFile.close();
    std::cout << "SAGE graph written into the file " << name << std::endl;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> ConvertEntriesMatrixToEdges(vector<vector<int>> the_entries, int threshold) 
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Construct the edge-vertex incidence matrix (d_1) from the distanceMatrix entries matrix:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<std::string> proteinNames;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges;
    std::cout << "Registering only edges shorter than " << threshold << "." << std::endl;
    int thisDistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < the_entries.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < the_entries.size(); j++)
        {
            // we could use the_entries.size() instead of the_entries.at(i).size(), because this is a square matrix.
            thisDistance = the_entries.at(i).at(j);
            if (thisDistance < threshold) 
            {
                std::vector<int> CurrentEdge(2);
                CurrentEdge[0] = i;
                CurrentEdge[1] = j;
                TheEdges.push_back(CurrentEdge);
            };
        };
    };
    return TheEdges;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Program: Extract edges from a distanceMatrix file.
///////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char** threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename)
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./distanceMatrixToSageGraph.o <threshold> <distanceMatrix_file_calculated_fromDGEsingleCell_data>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string distanceMatrixfilename = threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[2];
    int threshold = std::stoi(threshold_and_distanceMatrixfilename[1]);
    std::ifstream distanceMatrixFile(distanceMatrixfilename);
    if (!distanceMatrixFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening distanceMatrix file: " << distanceMatrixfilename << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string row;  //LINE 88
    std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row); // discard the first row, which specifies the format of the file.
    vector<vector<int>> the_entries;

    while (std::getline(distanceMatrixFile, row))
    {
        std::stringstream row_as_stringstream(row);
        int i; i = 0;
        vector<string> row_as_vector;
        while (row_as_stringstream.good())
        {
            string substr;
            getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ',');
            row_as_vector.push_back( std::stoi(substr) );
        };
        the_entries.push_back(row_as_vector); //LINE 104
    };
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Now we assemble the entries to an edges matrix, and write it into a Sage file:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> TheEdges = ConvertEntriesMatrixToEdges(the_entries, threshold);    
    char outputFilename[60]; strcpy(outputFilename, distanceMatrixfilename.c_str()); strcat(outputFilename, "AtThreshold"); string thrshld = std::to_string(threshold); strcat(outputFilename, thrshld.c_str()); strcat(outputFilename, ".txt");
    writeGraphInSageFormat(outputFilename, TheEdges);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... Instead of `argc<2 || argc > 2` why not just do `argc != 2` ?

Comment: If you have gdb, you can run it until it crashes, then do `bt` to see where things went wrong

Comment: Go through a debugger. Also your code is not compiling for some reason

Comment: The original `argc < 2 || argc > 3` means 1 or less or 4 or more.    The original `argc < 2 || argc > 2` means 1 or less or 3 or more.   The original and the changed version are not equivalent.   The original is equivalent to `argc != 2`

Comment: As @john pointed out `if (argc != 3)` is probably what I want, because the program name also counts as an argument. I have: `program arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question. What you're missing is that the program name is an argument, so

```
program arg1 arg2
```

is three arguments and `argc` will equal 3 not 2. You could have found this out for yourself by either using a debugger (you really need to learn how to use one, much better than asking here) or at the very least adding `cout << "argc=" << argc << '\n';` to your code.

Second question, your original code was written for comma separated values, see the comma here `getline(row_as_stringstream, substr, ',');` so obviously you need to change it for semi colon or space separated values.

Above all though you need to learn to use a debugger. Trying to debug programs by looking at code is not easy.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I was convinced it only counted arg1 and arg2 as arguments. `if (argc != 3)` should be the best thing to use then. For your second suggestion, that should actually solve the problem as far as I can see, which would be great. **EDIT:** Those steps seemed to have solved the problem and everything works fine now. Thank you very much